# What does out_channels in Conv2d represent?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()
```

I am taking a look at PyTorch Blitz and in the `conv1` layer we can see the `input_channels=3` because it's the first image so it just has its 3 RGB channels and `out_channels=6`.

Does that mean the number of filters I have are 6? In which case it'd mean the total number of feature maps I would get are `6*3==18`? But if that is the case why in `conv2` am I plugging in `input_channels=6`, shouldn't I be plugging in  18 because that was the output from the previous Convolutional layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you get the number of `out_channels` (that IS the number of feature maps). Imagine that you start off with 3 representations of your data - i.e., your input channels - you can choose how many representations you want after the convolutional operation, in this case you specified 6. Naturally, for the subsequent layer, you'll have 6 input channels.

It sounds like you don't fully grasp how convolutional neural networks work internally, look at some explanations like [here](https://indoml.com/2018/03/07/student-notes-convolutional-neural-networks-cnn-introduction/).

If you apply your case to the picture from that website, you'd have 6 different filters, leading to 6 output channels. The number you pick, is up to you!
[image]